# openerp 7: report not showing up

Tags: reporting, odoo

I created a report record via the interface but it doesn't show up in the print dropdown.

In settings -> actions -> reports, I added a new record:

```
Name: My Test

Service Name: my_po_reports

Object: purchase.order

Report Type: pdf

Report file: purchase/report/order.rml (i'm reusing an existing one just to test)
```

But My Test does NOT show up when I go to purchase order form!

I also tried the same in aeroo reports without any result:

In settings -> actions -> aeroo reports -> reports, I added a new record:

```
Name: My Test

Service Name: my_po_report

Object: purchase.order

Template type: odt Output type: odt

Template source: file Template path: myfolder/reports/template.odt
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: replacing my earlier solution with the following as this does not require an uninstall and reinstall:

```
<record id="report_mypo_test" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
    <field name="name">Stock Moves Report</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.report.xml</field>
    <field name="model">stock.move</field>
    <field name="report_name">mypo.test</field>
    <field name="report_type">aeroo</field>
    <field name="in_format">oo-odt</field>
    <field name="out_format" model="report.mimetypes" ref="report_aeroo.report_mimetypes_odt_odt"/>
    <field name="parser_loc">myaddon/reports/my_parser.py</field>
    <field name="report_rml">myaddon/reports/template.odt</field>
    <field name="parser_state">loc</field>
    <field name="tml_source">file</field>
</record>

<report auto="False" menu="True" id="report_mypo_test" model="stock.move" 
            name="mypo.test" rml="myaddon/reports/template.odt" string="Stock Moves Report"/>
```

my_parser.py:

```
import time
from tools.translate import _

from report import report_sxw
from report.report_sxw import rml_parse

from osv import fields, osv
import netsvc

class Parser(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(Parser, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context)

        ids =  self.pool.get('stock.move').search(self.cr, self.uid, [], context=context)
        self.stockmoves = self.pool.get('stock.move').browse(self.cr, self.uid, ids)

        self.localcontext.update({
            'stockmoves': self.stockmoves
        })
```

Credit to God Almighty, and many people who contribute their work on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

As you define actions for rml report. You have to also define one record for this report in action binding.

```
Settings ==> Actions ===> Action Bindings
```

Name : Purchase Order (Report Name to display)

Model Name: purchase.order (here your model)

Qualifier :  client_print_multi

Action Reference :  ir.actions.report.xml,360 (your report xml id here)

Hope this helpful to you

Regards,

Comment: Thanks. I believe that is the same as ir_set item that I am showing in my "answer". Please let me know if that is different. ir_set etc. didn't work for me, but someone hinted that if I uninstall and reinstall the module (and not just upgrade) it will show up. Let's see. Meanwhile, please look at my q: 15324570 regarding reporting over multiple POs, SOs, etc. Thanks

Comment: Yes, When you upgrade your module after restarting server then it will show up.